# trigger jquery tabs by date

Tags: jquery, date, tabs, jquery-tabs

I am using jquery tabs to filter some events that are happening for one week.
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

So i have the tab

```
   <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">1st June 2013</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">2nd June 2013</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">3rd June 2013</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want for example tab-1 to open on 1st June 2013 and then when the 2nd of june comes tab-2 will be the active tab on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`jQuery.now()`
to get the current date

Answer (score 0):

Kind of weird. You can do this way.

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1" data-date="2013-06-01">1st June 2013</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2" data-date="2013-06-02">2nd June 2013</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3" data-date="2013-06-03">3rd June 2013</a></li>
```

And once the page loads, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var today = (new Date()).getFullYear() + "-" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + "-" + (new Date()).getDate();
    $('[data-date="' + today + '"]').click();
});
```

And you will get open the current day's tab.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/f2Mav/

Comment: if thats the function to trigger tabs where do I add the javascript you have suggested?

'<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>'

Comment: next line to the `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` line and also, check out my updated answerr.

Comment: I have found this as I need to change an active state on a certain 
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
  });
</script>

but i need to create a function thats says if date 07/08/12 output the number = 7