# Javascript output Variable according to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, date, jquery-tabs

Hi I am trying to to use javascript to use a function thats says if date is 10/03/13 then output a single number like 1.

i need to apply this to a jquery tabs option.

Example:
09/03/13 output the number 2 in the active option

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
  });
</script>
```

10/03/13 output the number 3 so the code will look like this

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 3 );
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  Are you trying to say that you want to select a particular tab based on the date?

Comment: It depends, how are you storing your `date` variable? In the JS `Date` object? Or in a string?

Comment: its one tabs function with the number changing according to the date. so tomorw is the 10th I need the number 2 in the function to change to the number 3 :/ i hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm following up my comment with what I believe is the answer to your question.

First, you'd want to convert your date ranges to some sort of index that you could then use for tab selection.

```
<script>
    $(function(data) {
        var tabsList = [
            '03/09/2013',
            '03/10/2013',
            '03/11/2013',
            '03/12/2013'
        ];

        var tab = 0;
        for (var d=0;d<tabsList.length;d++) {
            if (tabsList[d]==data.Date) {
                tab = d;
                break;
            }
        }

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", tab );
    });
</script>
```

Essentially, you should have a unique tab index for each date range you want to recognize.  If this sounds like too much, then your approach to the problem is probably a little off and you may want to rethink the way you are tackling the problem.

EDIT:  I have cannibalized some of violent's code since you really need an array.  Data is whatever you pass into the function and should contain your current date or whatever date you want the function to think it is.

Comment: this makes sense! is it possible to add multiple else statements? im pretty bad at functions. I need to do the date changing with a number up everyday until the 17th of this month.

Comment: @mariovass  Asbsolutely!  You can add as many else if statements as you want, though you may way to look at something else like a fixed array at that point.  But for the easy example, yes, you can continue to add additional else if statements

Comment: Hi David, thanks for all your help. I tried this but it does't work.. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/mariovass/F47AV/

Comment: @mariovass I've updated the code to include some of Crayon Violent's answer concerning an array.  If you have that many unique dates you should be iterating through your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to say that you want to select a particular tab based on the date as @David said. Then you need to sort the dates array and return the index of the sorted array.

```
var dates = [
    '2013-11-08 18:58:50',
    '2013-11-09 17:49:42',
    // and so on...
];

dates.sort();
```

Or you need something like this [Sample for Nav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297266/2115255)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var cDate = new Date();
  var cYear = cDate.getFullYear().toString().substring(2);
  var cMonth = ((cDate.getMonth()+1)<10)? ("0"+(cDate.getMonth()+1) : (cDate.getMonth()+1);
  var cDay = (cDate.getDate()<10)? ("0"+cDate.getDate()) : cDate.getDate();
  cDateString = cMonth+'/'+cDay+'/'+cYear;
  var tabs = [
    "", // 0
    "", // 1
    "09/03/13", // 2
    "10/03/13" // 3
  ];
  var tab = 0;
  for (var d=0;d<tabs.length;d++) {
    if (tabs[d]==cDateString) {
      tab = d;
      break;
    }
  }
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", tab );
});
</script>
```